# verilog 32 bit wire port that can be an input or an output

Tags: verilog, port

In the verilog code below, is it creating a 32 bit wire port that can be an input or an output?

```
module test2 (CLOCK_50B, DUT0);

// Basic clocks
input  CLOCK_50B;

// parallel ports
inout  [31:0]  DUT0;

endmodule
```

Comment: Closing to vote as unclear, because it's not clear what you have doubts about – `inout` is not that hard to google for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. `DUT0` is a 32 bit wire that can be used to connect two modules. For example, you could wire the output of one module to the input of another module.

I could be wrong, but I don't believe you can directly assign a value to an `inout` wire. e.g. `DUT0 <= 0` would not be allowed for an `inout`.